# PHP simplehtmldom read only viewable text

Tags: php, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I have the following html format

```
 <p>This is viewable <span style="display:none">This is not viewable</span></p>
```

I want to use php simplehtmldom to extract only the "This is viewable" part.

Is there anyway to do it directly?

Comment: please, can you explain briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, just remove that text:

```
$str = '<p>This is viewable <span style="display:none">This is not viewable</span></p>';

$html = str_get_html($str);

foreach($html->find('[style*=display:none]') as $el){
  $el->innertext = '';
}

echo $html->find('p', 0)->text();
// This is viewable
```

Answer (score 0):

No, SimpleHTMLDOM is merely a DOM parser, it does not process the attributes in any meaningful way, let alone process inline styles. To properly do what you intend to achieve, it would also need to be able to process extended inline styles, like `style="anyother:'attribute';display:none"` and alternative ways of hiding content, like `visibility:hidden` and `opacity:0`, or brilliant stuff like `-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg)`.

In a nutshell, there is no remotely easy way to achieve the intended result.